# NextJS: Modify third-party component CSS in different pages

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar

With third-party components, the way to include their styles is by importing their stylesheet into `_app.tsx` or importing the stylesheet into your component that uses the third-party component, as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules or by adding to next.config.js like so:

```
// next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "@fullcalendar/common",
  "@fullcalendar/daygrid",
  "@fullcalendar/timegrid",
  "@fullcalendar/interaction",
  "@fullcalendar/react",
  "@fullcalendar/list",
```

To modify the third-party stylesheet, you need to create your own stylesheet and add it to `_app.tsx`; those modifications might look like this:

```
// styles/modified-fullcalendar.scss
.fc-col-header {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Another option, at least for my use case (Full Calendar) is to use CSS variables as described here in technique 2 on this page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization. There was a lengthy thread about this on the Full Calendar issues page, as seen here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5393

The problem with all of these methods of customization is that they're global, and so anywhere you use this third-party component it'll look the same. However, in my case, I want to use the component on two different pages, with different styling modifications. With most frameworks, I would simply import the relevant modified stylesheet wherever I needed it, but NextJS doesn't allow that. How can I achieve the modifications I want?

Comment: What about just having different classes in your modified css for the different pages and then applying the appropriate class names to your components so it targets the right css?

Comment: @adrian I think in this case I'm forced to use the same class names as what's provided in the third-party component in order to override their default values. So in the case of ".fc-col-header", I want it to have a width override of 100% in /foo/bar.tsx, and a width override of 50% in /foo/baz.tsx. I can't include them in respective css files, since I would need to do barStyles.module.css, which then makes the class name bar_fc-col-header and doesn't override the original. I may be misunderstanding your suggestion though, could you clarify if I have?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to wrap the component in a div with a specific class name, then do the css overrides in a nested format for each use case in the override file.

Explanation:

Say your third-party component is `FullCalendar`. It's being imported and used in the files `Foo.tsx` and `Bar.tsx`. In Foo, let's say you want the calendar cells to be green.

To make the modification, you create the file `modified-fc.scss` and do the following:

```
// modified-fc.scss
.fc-cell {
  background: green !important;
}
```

You then import `modified-fc.scss` into `_app.tsx` in order to apply the styles globally, and you're done. However, this prevents you from changing the cell color to orange in Bar. To circumvent this, just wrap the component:

```
// Foo.tsx
<div className=".wrapper1">
  <FullCalendar/>
</div>

// Bar.tsx
<div className=".wrapper2">
  <FullCalendar/>
</div>
```

and then nest the classes:

```
// modified-fc.scss
.wrapper1 {
  .fc-cell {
    background: green !important;
  }
}

.wrapper2 {
  .fc-cell {
    background: orange !important;
  }
}


OR

.wrapper1 > .fc-cell {
  background: green !important;
}

.wrapper2 > .fc-cell {
  background: orange !important;
}
```